# Grouping the results of two queries in eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a moderation reports queue like reddit. In the queue I want to have posts and comments show together, but all I can get is one, or the other with two queries:

```
//Get all posts with reports
Post::whereHas('reports')->with('reports.user')->latest()->get();
// Get all comments with reports
Comment::whereHas('reports')->with('reports.user')->latest()->get();
```

There is a polymorphic relationship with the comments, posts, and reports. table

**Here is the output for posts:**

```
{
 "id": 7,
 "author_id": 1,
 "title": "A forum post!",
 "body": "<p>Some Forum post content</p>",
 "created_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22",
 "updated_at": "2017-08-08 23:03:22",
 "reports": [
   {
      "id": 5,
      "user_id": 1,
      "content": "Rule 1",
      "reportable_id": 7,
      "reportable_type": "App\\Post",
      "created_at": "2017-08-11 19:32:02",
      "updated_at": "2017-08-11 19:32:02",
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "role_id": 1,
        "name": "Admin",
        "created_at": "2017-08-01 18:37:18",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-10 18:59:52"
       }
      }
     ]
},
```

How would I query both posts and comments?

*Edit*
I don't want to eager load the comments with the posts. I want join the two queries I listed above together. I feel after reading that I need to create a [union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions) between the two queries because I don't think I could join them together. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: tried this path `post->comment->reports->user` ? I don't mean this is a code, but following this path? is post and comments related?

Comment: You can eager load multiple relationship at once, try `Post::whereHas('reports')->with('reports.user', 'comment')->latest()->get();`

Comment: That would get the comments that exist for a post and not the comments that just have reports wouldn't it? I essentially want these two queries grouped together and then organized by latest:


`Post::whereHas('reports')->with('reports.user')`
`Comment::whereHas('reports')->with('reports.user')`

The top comment would get all of the comments associated with a post and not a comment that was reported. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of approaching this using posts or comments as the starting point, why not start with the reports model?  You said you were building a "moderation reports queue", which indicates that querying the reports table (and joining comments/posts) might be a more natural solution.

```
Reports::latest()->with('reportable', 'user')->get()
```

Eager loading was added to Laravel in PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13737

Comment: I was hoping to have a Posts/comments only listed once in the queue with a list of how many times they've been reported under them. Wouldn't that list a post/comment in the queue everytime it has been reported?

Comment: Do you want to list them in order of the most recent report, or the most recent post/comment?  If by recent reports, you could still query the reports table and group by post/comment, getting a count of the number of reports for each.

Comment: Most recent comment/post. Thank you for your help so far.